# How to differentiate between getting launched from a grouped notification or single one on iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications

On iOS 12, my notification delegate is getting called didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler, but I can't figure out if the user tapped on a single notification or on a collapsed group of notifications with just the most recent one in the response userInfo.

Calling getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler: just lets me know all the notifications that were delivered, not whether the user clicked on a single one or the group.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to catch that particular event?

Comment: If I was launched for a single event, I'd like to show the UI of the item generating the event. However, if multiple items ended up being grouped together, I don't want to show just the latest details.